# Why is "undefined" illegal as a request header value of Node's lib/http.js?

Tags: node.js, http-headers

The following code

```
const http = require('http')

const req = http.request('http://localhost:8080')
req.setHeader('x-api-key', undefined)
req.end()
```

gives a `ERR_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER_VALUE` error.

What might be the reason why this behavior is chosen?

Getting an unset header key with `req.getHeader` results in `undefined`, too. So from  a security standpoint how can just silently not setting the value become dangerous? Or is there any other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing about the error message mentions security in any way.

Header values have to be strings. If you pass `undefined` then it is probably because you are passing a variable and it is `undefined` by *mistake*. An error alerts you to that so you can fix it.

Use the [`removeHeader` method](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_removeheader_name) to unset a header.

Comment: ok, it's very liberal what value it accepts in any other way, though -- e. g. header values don't have to be strings, but are converted to strings when sent